# Difference between theme hooks and theme functions

Tags: drupal

Could someone please tell me the difference between theme hooks and theme functions in drupal. Sometimes they seem to be same and different at times. I am not being able to find a proper answer anywhere. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hook in Drupal takes precedence over a theme function.  The Drupal core takes them in a hierarchy of importance so you can customize things at the highest level.

A hook is specific to only the theme you're writing it in.  So bartik_form_alter() would be an extension of hook_form_alter() and therefore is prioritized in rendering.

The only non-hook theme function you should use in your template.php file is theme().  The other functions are further down the list and could be overridden.  It's also a performance issue to keep recurring through functions until one is found.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I should have been more specific. 
Some websites gives examples of "theme functions"  or "theme hooks" as 
http://api.drupal.org/api/group/themeable/7
So I understand that Theme functions are Functions and templates for the user interface to be implemented by themes. And Theme hooks are functions and template that have been specifically registered via hook_theme().
And when I go to https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7 I get lost. 
Or is that if I implement a hook in a theme, it becomes theme hook?

Comment: Yeah I've been up a while things are merging together.  When you make a theme, you make the file template.php.  When it says "theme hooks must register with hook_theme()" - this is where you do it.  It's nothing more than declaring the function and filling it with whatever code you want.  What I failed to explain earlier was hook_theme() is essentially just holding onto commonly used things (like menu links, tables, etc) that can be called through your template files to render quickly (and an index of all the themes/modules using hooks and which ones).  And I'm out of space almost lol